# Can we create an IF statement that determines if a variable has been declared as a pointer in C/C++

Tags: c++, pointers, if-statement

Suppose a variable `pa` is always declared as one of two ways:

> double * pa

OR

> double pa

Can we create an IF statement that does the following

> IF (pa is a pointer)
>   { pa[0] = 1
>   }
>
> ELSE 
>   { pa = 1}

EDIT:

Please see [How to find out if a pointer array has been filled in C++/C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6969584/how-to-find-out-if-a-pointer-array-has-been-filled-in-c-c) for the follow up question

Comment: This can probably be done at compile-time with templates.  The question is: why?  You would have to do this *everywhere* that you intend to use `pa`.  What situation requires this?

Comment: What are you **really** trying to do? The ways that `pa` are declared elsewhere in the program are utterly irrelevant to the specific way in which it is declared in the context of the if-statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not directly, no.  Suppose there were a way to do this, something like

```
if (__IS_POINTER(pa) {
    pa[0] = 1;
}
else {
    a = 1;
}
```

What happens if pa *isn't* a pointer?  You still have that `pa[0] = 1;` statement in your program, and it's illegal, so the compiler is going to reject your program.

You might in principle be able to do a compile-time test:

```
#if __pa_IS_A_POINTER
pa[0] = 1;
#else
a = 1
#endif
```

but the power of the C++ preprocessor is very limited; it has no way to test the type of a variable or expression.

If you had this capability, what would you do with it?  Tell us what your actual goal is.

Comment: OK I understand this answer. I will add new question that explains my problem differently.

Comment: It can be done though. See any implementation of `type_traits`, such as Boost's, which has an `is_pointer` template. :) but what the OP is asking for isn't possible for the reasons you say.

Answer (score 6):

The basics of how C++0x `std::is_pointer` might work:

```
template <typename T>
struct is_pointer_helper {
    static const bool value = false;
};

template <template T>
struct is_pointer_helper<T*> {
    static const bool value = true;
};
```

For this example we don't want to have to use the type, so we need some template argument deduction:

```
template <typename T>
bool is_pointer(const T &) {
    return is_pointer_helper<T>::value;
}
```

And we're done:

```
if (is_pointer(pa)) {
    pa[0] = 1;
} else {
    pa = 1;
}
```

BUT, note that this code still won't compile unless `pa[0] = 1` and `pa = 1` are both valid expressions (and for neither `double` nor `double*` are they both valid - if you were setting to `0` then both would be valid for `double*`, but still only the second for `double`). So probably what you want is not an explicit "if" test, but an overloaded function:

```
template <typename T>
void set_thingy(T &t) {
    t = 1;
}

template <typename T>
void set_thingy(T *pt) {
    set_thingy(*pt);
}

set_thingy(pa);
```

Or, since `pa` is always `double` or `double*`, there's no need to focus on the fact that one is a pointer and the other is not, they're just two different types that we need to treat differently. So no need for templates:

```
void set_thingy(double &d) { d = 1; }
void set_thingy(double *p) { *p = 1; }

set_thingy(pa);
```

Comment: Both brances should be compilable even if only one branch is always executed. Your code wouldn't compile.

Comment: @Nawaz: And apparently it said that from the very first version, check the revision history ;-). SO doesn't do anything to stop people commenting on a version of a question that has changed before the comment was made. You must have loaded the page in the narrow window after I typed the code, but before I added the BUT, so however long it took me to type two lines.

Comment: Maybe its from the very first version and I skipped reading that part. If that is the case, then I apologize for my first comment and please feel free to ignore it. However, I cannot check the revision history to see that, since within `5` mins you can edit your post as many times as you want, for which SO doesn't maintain any revision history. By the way, +1 for most detailed and complete answer. :-)

Comment: @Nawaz: Sorry, I was joking when I said "apparently" - it wasn't really from the first version, I posted the answer gradually because I figured someone else might be about to type out the exact same template and specialization, and might as well see as early as possible that they needn't bother. 5 minutes was about my 3rd version.

Answer (score 0):

In C++0x you can, using type traits and `decltype`:

```
#include <type_traits>

if (std::is_pointer<decltype(x)>::value)
{
  /* ... */
}
```

In C++98/03 you don't have `decltype`, but now you'd have to explain how you could possibly have a variable without knowing its type. If you do have its type, you can use the same type trait:

```
#include <tr1/type_traits>
template <typename T> void bogus(T x) // T could be a pointer or not
{
  if (std::tr1::is_pointer<T>::value) { /*...*/ }
}
```

You can also just define your own trait class if you don't have or want to use TR1:

```
template <typename> struct is_pointer { static const bool value = false; };
template <typename T> struct is_pointer<T*> { static const bool value = true; };
```