# How to find out if a pointer array has been filled in C++/C

Tags: c++, pointers, if-statement

Suppose I have function

> foo(double * pa)

where `pa` is either populated from [0] to [100] 
OR 
`pa` is populated for [0] only.

My function does the following:

> foo(double * pa)
>
> {
>
> IF (pa is an array of 100)  THEN x[0 to 100] = pa[0 to 100]
>
> ELSE  x[0 to 100] = pa[0]
>
> }

Comment: Why not just use a vector and check it's size?

Comment: Excellent question: 1) if you have a raw C array, the called function cannot know the size.  2) an STL container (like a vector) doesn't have this problem - you CAN query the size (and, depending on the container, also change it at will)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Q: How is foo() going to know whether pa[] is an array of 100?

In general, you have to TELL it.  For example:

```
void
foo (double *pa, int len)
{
  if (len == 100)
    ...
  else
    ...
```

If you were coding in C++, however, you could use an STL container such as a vector:

```
void foo (vector<double> & pa)
{
  if (pa.size() == 100)
    ...
```

Answer (score 4):

That's not possible. `pa` isn't *populated*, because it is not an array. It is a pointer which, by convention, points to the first element of an array. But its type is simply `pointer to double`, and it has no information about whether it points to a single double, or an array of 1, 10, 100 or 1000 elements.

The "traditional" solution would be to pass two parameters, the pointer and the size of the array:

```
void foo(double* pa, size_t arraysize)
{
    if (arraysize == 100) {
        ...
    }
    else {
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Can't we check the value of say pa[100] and see if the value is a "normal" value, thus implying the array has been populated.

Comment: @gamma123: No.  If pa points to something shorter than a 101-element array, then just referring to `pa[100]` invokes undefined behavior.  (N.B.: the last element of a 100-element array is `pa[99]`, not `pa[100]`.)

Comment: OK cant we check if pa[99] is a normal value then

Comment: No, you miss the point. `pa` could point to **anything** of the appropriate type. It can point to an individual `double` just as easily as it points to an array, and there is **no way** for the function to find out. `pa[99]` is not necessarily something we are *allowed to do*.

Comment: there is no "normal" or "non-normal" value. It just points to a memory location, where you may or may not have written a double. If you have, go ahead and read it. If you haven't, there are *no* guarantees about what will happen if you try to read it. You might get a segmentation fault/access violation, or you might read some random garbage value out from memory. You're just pointing at a memory address and going "what's over there?"

Answer (score 1):

Given the information in the `foo()` function parameters, it is not possible to find out:

- the number of elements that are "filled in"
- the total number of elements in the array pointed to by `pa`

In order to accomplish this, you will need to pass additional parameters to the `foo()` function that state how big the total array is, and how many elements have been filled in.

Comment: Can't we check the value of say pa[100] and see if the value is a "normal" value, thus implying the array has been populated. Assuming the normal range is from -10 to +10.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6969465/can-we-create-an-if-statement-that-determines-if-a-variable-has-been-declared-as), combined with this question, I think what you may want is simply an overload, see here:

```
void foo_impl(double * x)
{
    // common functionality here
}

void foo(double * pa)
{
    double x[100];
    std::copy(pa, pa + 100, x);
    foo_impl(x);
}

void foo(double pa)
{
    double x[100];
    std::fill(x,x+100,pa);
    foo_impl(x);
}
```

With this, you can call foo with a pointer, where it's assumed to be pointing to an array with at least 100 values.  Or you can call it with a single value.  Put the common functionality between the two functions in `foo_impl`, that way you're not duplicating code.

Answer (score 0):

You can't.  The only thing `foo()` knows `pa` is that it's a pointer, whether it's a null pointer or not, and if it's non-null, what it points to.  It can't tell whether it points to a single object or to the first element of an array.

If possible, you should probably `foo()` so the caller has to pass in additional information:

```
void foo(double *pa, size_t count) {
    /* ... */
}
```

(Note: you should declare `foo`'s return type.)